# free hand drawing in java using class Point

Tags: java, applet, mouselistener

I am trying to write a simple free hand drawing code in java using Point class and arraylist but i am getting stuck. Firstly, cant really leave the origin point, and secondly ther's always a line drawn between the 2 points even when mouse is not dragged.

```
public class FreeDraw extends Applet implements MouseMotionListener
{
     int x,y,m,n;
     ArrayList<Point> al;
     public void init()
     {
         al = new ArrayList<>();

        this.addMouseMotionListener(this);

     }
      public void paint(Graphics g)
      {

          for(int i=0;i<al.size();i++)
          {
               m=al.get(i).x;
               n=al.get(i).y;

               g.drawLine(m,n,x,y);  

               x=m;
               y=n;

          }
      }
     public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)
     {
        al.add(new Point(e.getX(),e.getY()));
        repaint(); 
     }


    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e)
    {
    //do nothing
    }

}
```

Comment: FYI: [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to seed the initial x/y position (otherwise `m` and `n` will be `0x0` to the first point)

Something like...

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    if (!al.isEmpty()) {
        int x = al.get(0).x;
        int y = al.get(0).y;
        for (int i = 1; i < al.size(); i++) {
            m = al.get(i).x;
            n = al.get(i).y;

            g.drawLine(m, n, x, y);

            x = m;
            y = n;

        }
    }
}
```

for example.

Apart from the fact that `Applet` was replaced with `JApplet` some 16 years ago, the applet plugin is no longer supported by Oracle, but most of the browsers actively block it, making it a dead end technology.

See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free) for more details

Comment: it solves upto a point but still 2 different points are joined even when thy are not supposed too. BTW thanks.

Comment: So between clicks you want the lines to be separated?  In that case, on `mouseClicked` (from `MouseListener`), you'll need to create a new `List` into which you can add the drag `Point`s.  This `List` (and all the others you will create) will be added to another `List`, you will then need compound loops to loop through the outer and inner loops